# Expected Value for Arrows game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

> In a game Daniel shoot arrows on a circular target with a radius of $R$.
>
> Daniel's arrows hit the target uniformly distributed over the target.
>
> Daniel shoots one arrow on a circular target with radius R, that is
> split into $10$ circles each with similar size $((R^2\pi)/10)$ such
> that the innermost circle gives $10$ points, the second innermost gives $9$ and so on till the outermost gives $1$ point. What's the expected value for the points he got?

---

Let D be a random variable that measures the distance from the center.

Previously I found with your help that $E(D)=(2R)/3$ from there I think I should find the circle within that radius and multiply with points. But I'm not sure how to do this formally or find that circle.

Comment: If I'm right it's in the 5th circle, so Expected value is 5 but that's not formal at all

Comment: Oh, Actually I could use function for points right? there is a formula for expected value of function But should the function be according to distance or number of circle

Comment: What does it look like? Is it like the picture where the inner most area is the same as the blue area and etc? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMIbl.png

Comment: @cr001 yes that one

Comment: Then I think the expected points is just $1\times{9\over 10}+10\times{1\over 10}$

Comment: why is that? what do you mean by expected points? it's a normal number between 1 and 10

Comment: It means "expected value for the points he got". The expected value is defined as the sum of each possible value times the probability of that value occurring. We have $9\over 10$ chances that a one-point scenario occurring and $1\over 10$ chances that a 10-point scenario occurring as told in the question.

Comment: What is the scheme of points? $10,9,9,...,9,1$ or $10,9,8,...,3,2,1$? It is not clear in the question.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri the inner circle as I said is 10 then 9 then 8 until the last one which gives 1 point

Comment: @cr001 "We have 9/10 chances that a one-point scenario" not true it's only 1/10 of the total area how could you suppose something like this

Comment: If all the circles are equal in area, then the arrow will land on every circle with the same probability $1/10$. The expected value of the points is $\frac1{10}(1+2+...+9+10)=11/2$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thanks, could you write it as answer with more details and formal steps to help others as well?

Comment: @MrCalc I think the wording has changed. Originally it stated the inner most is 10 points and all other 9 circles are 1 point if I remember correctly...well if I misread the statement before then sorry.

Comment: @cr001 I have edited the question to reflect the true intention of OP. They meant that the points vary from $10\to9\to8\to7\to\cdot\cdot\cdot\to1$ from the innermost to the outermost circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is given that the arrow lands on the target uniformly. This means the probability of landing on a circle is proportional to the area of the circle. In this case we have $10$ circles of equal area, so the probability  that the arrow lands on any circle is $1/10$. The expected value of the points is$$\frac1{10}[1+2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+10]=\frac{11}2.$$

Comment: Thanks for this